# I installed nodejs on WSL2, but cant call it from windows

Tags: node.js, windows, wsl-2

I have installed Node 18 on Ubuntu on WSL2 in Windows 11.  (plus eslint, which is the main end goal)  When I'm in the Ubuntu terminal, everything works fine.  I can even eslint my code on the windows file system via `/mnt/c/somefolder/...` - cool!

When I try to call it from the Windows command prompt, I get "command not found"

```
C:\Windows>wsl node --version
/bin/bash: line 1: node: command not found
```

Other standard linux commands work fine, e.g. `wsl ls` or `wsl nano foo.txt` work as intended (though the current directory differs)

I'm guessing it's something about a PATH to node, but my Google-fu has failed me for a solution.

**EDIT, FIXED (sort of)**: This seems to be *NVM related*.  When I do a basic install of a single version of node in /usr/bin using Ubuntu `apt-get` (doing the tricks to get the more recent v18.2 LTS) it all works o.k.  I don't need NVM for now...

**EDIT 2**
I can't get the VSCode (running under windows, with the ESLint extension) to connect to the node and eslint code under WSL.  Which might just be impossible.  Is it?